# How to automatically select <option>s in blue instead of grey

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying a simple website feature consisting in a select with some options in it. I want to allow selection using keyboard numbers only, but in the system I am trying this feature on (Internet Explorer Mobile) I can't do it without at least a click on the options.

Code is the following:

```
<body>
    Press a key to select an option

    <select id="choose" size="7">
        <option value="1">Volvo</option>
        <option value="2">Saab</option>
        <option value="3">Opel</option>
        <option value="4">Audi</option>
        <option value="5">Citroen</option>
    </select>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#choose").prop("selectedIndex", 3); 
            $(document).keydown(function(e) {   
                if (e.which > 48 && e.which < 54) {
                    $("#choose").val(e.which - 49);
                }if (e.keyCode > 48 && e.keyCode < 54) {
                    $("#choose").val(e.keyCode - 49);
                }
            });
        });             
    </script>
</body>
```

It works on Chrome, but I noticed the page loads with a strange grey background on the selected option 
[image: Grey selection]
 instead of the normal blue one, that appears after clicking on it 
[image: blue selection]

Unfortunately Internet Explorer Mobile does not seem to recognize the grey option background, while after clicking on it (thus changing the background from grey to blue) the "keyboard selection" works perfectly.

How can I make the option background blue in the first place, as soon as the page loads?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `.focus()`:

```
$("#choose").prop("selectedIndex", 3).focus();
```

or simply set the value like:

```
$("#choose").val(3).focus();
```